# Virtual methods Optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, virtual

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass{
    int somedata;
  public:
    virtual void DoSomething() { /*do something here*/}
};
```

And then I never derive from this class ever.  I realize that if the compiler just writes the assembly exactly the way the code is written, every single `MyClass` instance has an added data size because of the virtual function.....

So is it standard conforming for the optimizer to optimize the class something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    int somedata;
  public:
    void DoSomething() { /*do something here*/}  //Note absence of virtual
};
```

If it is a standard conforming optimization, does any compiler even do this?

Comment: Can you write a conforming program that can tell the difference?

Comment: @PeteBecker Maybe if I had an array of `MyClass`es and then used a `void` pointer to access members...but that is quite extreme...

Comment: You can't access members through a `void` pointer in a conforming program.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes but I could increment my void pointer to point to the next `MyClass` assuming that it is bigger than it actually is which could cause me to skip elements (maybe...I am just making this up to try to find something)

Comment: You can't increment a `void` pointer. But that aside, any guess you make about the size of your class is just that: a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is standards conforming for the compiler and the linker to do anything their heart desires, as long as it has no effect on the expected behavior of the code, such as the example you cited.

I distinctly recall browsing through recent `gcc` release notes a specific mention that, in cooperation with the linker, it does exactly this.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the final keyword introduced in C++11 standard.

```
Class My class {

Public:
Void doSomething () final;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced this answers the question, but I suspect it could with a bit more explanation.